# entityManager.flush() will clear the second level cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

A bit confused with the `entityManger.flush();`

Hibernate doc for batching

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/chapters/batch/Batching.html

"When you make new objects persistent, employ methods flush() and clear() to the session regularly, to control the size of the first-level cache."

I am working on spring boot data jpa.

The first doubt is for Restful applications first level cache is enabled or not?

Can the `entityManager.flush()` clears the second level cache?

Is `entityManger.flush()` is similar to `System.gc()`;

Comment: No. why would it?

Comment: I think the idea was to call flush() to make sure you don't lose any changes made so far and then clear() to unload entities from the persistence context

Answer (score 3):

**1)** First level cache is created per started transaction, so its always there for each transactional method.

**2)** `entityManager.flush()`, does not clear the second level cache. It also does not clear the first level cache, it enforces any changes done in the current transaction to be pushed into the physical database.

3) Is `entityManger.flush()` is similar to `System.gc()`? No, all the objects are still on the heap and are even still managed by the current persistence context.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/chapters/batch/Batching.html says   "When you make new objects persistent, employ methods flush() and clear() to the session regularly, to control the size of the first-level cache"

Comment: That all depends on what is going on in the tranactional method but thats too broad of a subject.. in general if you are qerying persisting and updating a lot in one transaction you should use those methods but again.. not in excess

Comment: First level cache is associated with the “session” object. The scope of cache objects is of a session. Once the session is closed, cached objects are gone forever. In a restful web service, its stateless. so when there is a session how the first level cache works?

Comment: They are not gone, they are detached from the persistence context, but are still normal object living on the heap which can be merged back to a new session at any time

Comment: Does Restful Webservice have sessions? If there is no session then how first level cache works?

Comment: First level cache is typically used for the duration of a **unit of work**, i.e. if you call `EntityManager.find(MyEntity.class, 5L)` **twice in a single transaction**, then the second time around, the entity will be served from first-level cache. It has nothing to do with Web sessions, its lifecycle is bound to that of the transaction